# Using "Learning Python with Raspberry Pi" from Wiley where does prev_grade come from?

Tags: python

```
def print_report_card(report_student = None):
    for student in students:
        if (student[0] == report_student) or (report_student == None):
            print("Report card for student ", student[0])            
            for subject, mark in student[1].items():
                for grade in grades:
                    if mark < grade[0]:
                        print(subject, " : ", prev_grade)
                        break
                    prev_grade = grade[1]
```

Struggling to understand this fragment:

```
for grade in grades:
    if mark < grade[0]:
        print(subject, " : ", prev_grade)
        break
    prev_grade = grade[1]
```

Grades is a tuple of tuples

`grades = ((0, "FAIL"),(50, "D"),(60,"C"),(70, "B"), (80," A"), (101, "CHEAT!"))`
 and students is a list of list with dictionaries

```
students = [["Ben", {"Maths": 67, "English": 78, "Science": 72}],
            ["Mark", {"Maths": 56, "Art": 64, "History": 39, "Geography": 55}],
            ["Paul", {"English": 66, "History": 88}]]
```

**But no idea where the prev_grade bit comes from and how it works, any help?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`prev_grade` is the grade string that was found on the previous iteration of the

```
for grade in grades:
```

loop. When we first enter that loop `grade` gets set to `(0, "FAIL")`, so `grade[0]` is zero. And because `mark` is always >= 0 the following test

```
if mark < grade[0]:
```

*can't* be true, so we don't enter the `if` block, and so it doesn't matter that `prev_grade` doesn't exist yet because we aren't going to attempt to print it on this iteration of the loop. So we skip over the `if` block and come to

```
prev_grade = grade[1]
```

which sets `prev_grade` so it can be used on the next round of the `for` loop. We need `prev_grade` because we don't know what the grade is until we see a `grade` tuple with `grade[0]` that's greater than `mark`, and then we know that the proper grade string is the one from the previous `grade` tuple.

The best way to really understand what's going on is to manually "execute" the code on paper. Pretend that you're the Python interpreter and follow the instructions in the code, and see what happens.

But if you don't have the patience to do that it can help if you add a few extra print statements to the code, like this:

```
grades = (
    (0, "FAIL"), 
    (50, "D"), 
    (60,"C"), 
    (70, "B"), 
    (80, "A"), 
    (101, "CHEAT!")
)

students = [
    ["Ben", {"Maths": 67, "English": 78, "Science": 72}],
    ["Mark", {"Maths": 56, "Art": 64, "History": 39, "Geography": 55}],
    ["Paul", {"English": 66, "History": 88}],
]

def print_report_card(report_student=None):
    for student in students:
        if (student[0] == report_student) or (report_student is None):
            print("\nReport card for student ", student[0])
            for subject, mark in student[1].items():
                print('\nSUBJECT', subject, 'MARK', mark)
                for grade in grades:
                    print('GRADE', grade)
                    if mark < grade[0]:
                        print(subject, " : ", prev_grade)
                        break
                    print('SETTING prev_grade TO', grade[1])
                    prev_grade = grade[1]

print_report_card("Paul")
```

**output**

```
Report card for student  Paul

SUBJECT English MARK 66
GRADE (0, 'FAIL')
SETTING prev_grade TO FAIL
GRADE (50, 'D')
SETTING prev_grade TO D
GRADE (60, 'C')
SETTING prev_grade TO C
GRADE (70, 'B')
English  :  C

SUBJECT History MARK 88
GRADE (0, 'FAIL')
SETTING prev_grade TO FAIL
GRADE (50, 'D')
SETTING prev_grade TO D
GRADE (60, 'C')
SETTING prev_grade TO C
GRADE (70, 'B')
SETTING prev_grade TO B
GRADE (80, 'A')
SETTING prev_grade TO A
GRADE (101, 'CHEAT!')
History  :  A
```

---

It can be argued that it's bad style to refer to `prev_grade` in that `if` block when it hasn't been defined earlier. Sure, my analysis shows that it's safe, and it shouldn't faze an experienced coder, but it still slows you down reading stuff like that. It'd be *much* better (IMHO) to define `prev_grade` outside the loop, or at least have a comment explaining what's going on. Or do both. :)

```
for subject, mark in student[1].items():
    prev_grade = None
    for grade in grades:
        # This condition can never be True on the first loop iteration
        if mark < grade[0]:
            print(subject, " : ", prev_grade)
            break
        prev_grade = grade[1]
```

---

You may notice that I changed `(report_student == None)` to `(report_student is None)`, the latter is more efficient and is recommended in the Python Style Guide, [PEP-0008](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008).

Comment: Thank you for your explanation and now you pointed out that in the for loop the if mark < grade[0] code always is false 1st time round it makes sense. I have been trained of the school that variable are assigned a value prior to or at first appearance in the code, hence the confusion.

Answer (score 0):

IMO this code is needlessly convoluted. It relies on the fact that the `if mark < grade[0]` is *always* false on the first iteration, since the first item from `grades`:

```
grades = ((0, "FAIL"),(50, "D"),(60,"C"),(70, "B"), (80," A"), (101, "CHEAT!"))
```

`grades[0]` is `0`. And every number in `students` is greater than `0`. So the `if` body is skipped and we arrive at:

```
prev_grade = grade[1]
```

So the next time it loops and enters the `if` body, `prev_grade` will be defined. What if there *were* a grade less than 0:

```
In [3]: students = [["Ben", {"Maths": -1, "English": 78, "Science": 72}],
   ...:             ["Mark", {"Maths": 56, "Art": 64, "History": 39, "Geography": 55}],
   ...:             ["Paul", {"English": 66, "History": 88}]]
   ...:
```

Now we try to call the function:

```
In [4]: print_report_card()
Report card for student  Ben
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
UnboundLocalError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-6-aa68f0bb7206> in <module>()
----> 1 print_report_card()

<ipython-input-2-9f9e72e91ef4> in print_report_card(report_student)
      6                 for grade in grades:
      7                     if mark < grade[0]:
----> 8                         print(subject, " : ", prev_grade)
      9                         break
     10                     prev_grade = grade[1]

UnboundLocalError: local variable 'prev_grade' referenced before assignment
```

And we get the `UnboundLocalError` you might expect.

Comment: Thanks I do understand this and again assigning value at first use would prevent this.

Answer (score 0):

The prev_grade is used to remember the previous grade[1] that was checked before entering the code in the if statement:

```
if mark < grade[0]:
      print(subject, " : ", prev_grade)
break
```

The code in the if statement will be performed if the grade value is bigger than the mark value. When the value is bigger than the mark means that the previous grade value is the grade value that the student receives as result.

If you printed the current grade[1] that you have when entering the if statement then the displayed grade value is the wrong value because its one grade value to big. You can test this in your code by changing the "prev_grade" to "grade[1]" in your code. When printing the values you will see that for the grade[0] value "67" the desired value "C" is changed to the value "B" instead.

Comment: Thanks for your answer